# How to assign mysql result to variable (in C)

Tags: mysql, c

I can't assign the result of query to variable (the program is written in C). Here is what I do

```
char buffer[100];

while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL) {
   buffer = row[0];
}
```

A get this error during compile process

```
error: incompatible types in assignment
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What is row? Is it a char array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's a string? C doesn't have strings it has arrays of characters. So you have copy the characters from one array to another.

so use a copy function like

```
strncpy(buffer, row[0], 100);
```

Comment: Also, be sure that a length of 100 is enough.

Comment: A note mainly to the question asker: mysql_fetch_lengths can be used to know how long (in bytes) each field is.